# I am having trouble in running the KinesisVideoRekognitionLambdaExample.java in stream parser library

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, video-streaming, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I am getting compile errors and "Build Failure" errors when I run this code 'https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library#kinesisvideorekognitionlambdaexample'

I tried the steps mentioned [SS of steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oMbm.png) to run the code.
I am expecting to see the stream video with bounding box in the aws console but, it throws errors.
These are the errors I am getting

```
docker ps
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\sam.cmd" build Function --template "D:\Stream Parser\java-stream-parser\java-stream-parser-master\.aws-sam\temp-template.yaml" --build-dir "D:\Stream Parser\java-stream-parser\java-stream-parser-master\.aws-sam\build" --use-container
Starting Build inside a container
Building codeuri: D:\Stream Parser\java-stream-parser\java-stream-parser-master runtime: java8.al2 metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: Function

Fetching public.ecr.aws/sam/build-java8.al2:latest-x86_64 Docker container image......
Mounting D:\Stream Parser\java-stream-parser\java-stream-parser-master as /tmp/samcli/source:ro,delegated inside runtime container

Build Failed
Running JavaMavenWorkflow:CopySource
Running JavaMavenWorkflow:MavenBuild
Error: JavaMavenWorkflow:MavenBuild - Maven Failed: [INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.4.0.RELEASE.pom 
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-1.4.0.RELEASE.pom (87 kB at 121 kB/s)  
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-bom/4.3.1.RELEASE/spring-integration-bom-4.3.1.RELEASE.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----< com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library >------
[INFO] Building Amazon Kinesis Video Streams Parser Library 1.0.15
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/3.1.1/maven-javadoc-plugin-3.1.1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/18/apache-18.pom (16 kB at 38 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar (640 kB at 180 kB/s)
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 93 source files to /tmp/samcli/scratch/target/classes
[INFO] /tmp/samcli/scratch/target/generated-sources/delombok/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/parser/kinesis/KinesisDataStreamsWorker.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[INFO] /tmp/samcli/scratch/target/generated-sources/delombok/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/parser/kinesis/KinesisDataStreamsWorker.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] /tmp/samcli/scratch/target/generated-sources/delombok/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/parser/mkv/MkvDataElement.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /tmp/samcli/scratch/target/generated-sources/delombok/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/parser/mkv/MkvDataElement.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- lombok-maven-plugin:1.18.16.0:testDelombok (test-delombok) @ amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library ---
[WARNING] Skipping Test Delombok; no source to process.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 16 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 23 source files to /tmp/samcli/scratch/target/test-classes
[INFO] /tmp/samcli/scratch/src/test/java/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/parser/utilities/OutputSegmentMergerTest.java: /tmp/samcli/scratch/src/test/java/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/parser/utilities/OutputSegmentMergerTest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[INFO] /tmp/samcli/scratch/src/test/java/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/parser/utilities/OutputSegmentMergerTest.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] /tmp/samcli/scratch/src/test/java/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/parser/ebml/TestEBMLTypeInfoProvider.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /tmp/samcli/scratch/src/test/java/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/parser/ebml/TestEBMLTypeInfoProvider.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library ---
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.18.1/maven-surefire-common-2.18.1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.18.1/maven-surefire-common-2.18.1.pom (6.3 kB at 11 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.3/maven-plugin-annotations-3.3.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.3/maven-plugin-annotations-3.3.pom (1.6 kB at 2.8 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools/3.3/maven-plugin-tools-3.3.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools/3.3/maven-plugin-tools-3.3.pom (13 kB at 23 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-grouper/2.18.1/surefire-grouper-2.18.1.jar (38 kB at 62 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/common-java5/2.18.1/common-java5-2.18.1.jar (37 kB at 58 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-testng/2.18.1/surefire-testng-2.18.1.jar (37 kB at 57 kB/s)

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator
Usage: <main class> [options] The XML suite files to run
  Options:
    -configfailurepolicy               Configuration failure policy (skip or
                                       continue)
    -d                                 Output directory
    -dataproviderthreadcount           Number of threads to use when running
                                       data providers
    -excludegroups                     Comma-separated list of group names to 
                                       exclude
    -groups                            Comma-separated list of group names to be
                                       run
    -junit                             JUnit mode
                                       Default: false
    -listener                          List of .class files or list of class
                                       names implementing ITestListener or
                                       ISuiteListener
    -methods                           Comma separated of test methods
                                       Default: []
    -methodselectors                   List of .class files or list of class
                                       names implementing IMethodSelector
    -mixed                             Mixed mode - autodetect the type of
                                       current test and run it with appropriate runner
                                       Default: false
    -objectfactory                     List of .class files or list of class
                                       names implementing ITestRunnerFactory
    -parallel                          Parallel mode (methods, tests or classes)
    -port                              The port
    -reporter                          Extended configuration for custom report
                                       listener
    -suitename                         Default name of test suite, if not
                                       specified in suite definition file or source code
    -suitethreadpoolsize               Size of the thread pool to use to run
                                       suites
                                       Default: 1
    -testclass                         The list of test classes
    -testjar                           A jar file containing the tests
    -testname                          Default name of test, if not specified in
                                       suitedefinition file or source code
    -testnames                         The list of test names to run
    -testrunfactory, -testRunFactory   The factory used to create tests
    -threadcount                       Number of threads to use when running
                                       tests in parallel
    -usedefaultlisteners               Whether to use the default listeners
                                       Default: true
    -log, -verbose                     Level of verbosity
    -xmlpathinjar                      The full path to the xml file inside the
                                       jar file (only valid if -testjar was
                                       specified)
                                       Default: testng.xml

Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator
fbb4f85f168dc4fa
Tests run: 73, Failures: 7, Errors: 0, Skipped: 6, Time elapsed: 21.919 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
testWithWebmVideo on testWithWebmVideo(com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.utilities.SimpleFrameVisitorTest)(com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.utilities.SimpleFrameVisitorTest)  Time elapsed: 0.008 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: testdata/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.TestResourceUtil.getTestInputStream(TestResourceUtil.java:37)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.utilities.SimpleFrameVisitorTest.getInputStreamParserByteSource(SimpleFrameVisitorTest.java:124)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.utilities.SimpleFrameVisitorTest.getClustersByteSource(SimpleFrameVisitorTest.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.utilities.SimpleFrameVisitorTest.testWithWebmVideo(SimpleFrameVisitorTest.java:71)

testFragmentMetadata_NoFragementMetadata_withWebm on testFragmentMetadata_NoFragementMetadata_withWebm(com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.utilities.FragmentMetadataVisitorTest)(com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.utilities.FragmentMetadataVisitorTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: testdata/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.TestResourceUtil.getTestInputStream(TestResourceUtil.java:37)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.utilities.FragmentMetadataVisitorTest.testFragmentMetadata_NoFragementMetadata_withWebm(FragmentMetadataVisitorTest.java:269)

frameCountTest on frameCountTest(com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.utilities.FrameRendererTest)(com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.utilities.FrameRendererTest)  Time elapsed: 0.004 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoFrameViewer.<init>(KinesisVideoFrameViewer.java:31)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoFrameViewer.<init>(KinesisVideoFrameViewer.java:40)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.utilities.FrameRendererTest.frameCountTest(FrameRendererTest.java:47)

frameCountTest2 on frameCountTest2(com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.utilities.FrameRendererTest)(com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.utilities.FrameRendererTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoFrameViewer.<init>(KinesisVideoFrameViewer.java:31)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoFrameViewer.<init>(KinesisVideoFrameViewer.java:40)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.utilities.FrameRendererTest.frameCountTest2(FrameRendererTest.java:79)

testDifferentResolution on testDifferentResolution(com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest)(com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest)  Time elapsed: 0.645 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: profile file cannot be null
    at com.amazonaws.util.ValidationUtils.assertNotNull(ValidationUtils.java:37)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:142)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:133)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:100)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:135)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1214)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:790)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:740)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:733)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:675)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:657)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:521)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:960)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:927)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:916)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.executeDescribeStream(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:364)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.describeStream(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:336)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.StreamOps.getStreamInfo(StreamOps.java:106)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.StreamOps.createStreamIfNotExist(StreamOps.java:65)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoRendererExample.execute(KinesisVideoRendererExample.java:76)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest.testDifferentResolution(KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest.java:52)

testExample on testExample(com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest)(com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest)  Time elapsed: 0.003 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: profile file cannot be null
    at com.amazonaws.util.ValidationUtils.assertNotNull(ValidationUtils.java:37)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:142)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:133)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:100)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:135)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1214)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:790)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:740)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:733)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:675)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:657)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:521)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:960)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:927)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:916)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.executeDescribeStream(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:364)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.describeStream(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:336)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.StreamOps.getStreamInfo(StreamOps.java:106)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.StreamOps.createStreamIfNotExist(StreamOps.java:65)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoRendererExample.execute(KinesisVideoRendererExample.java:76)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest.testExample(KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest.java:38)

testConsumerExample on testConsumerExample(com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest)(com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest)  Time elapsed: 0.004 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: profile file cannot be null
    at com.amazonaws.util.ValidationUtils.assertNotNull(ValidationUtils.java:37)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:142)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:133)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:100)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:135)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1214)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:790)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:740)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:733)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:675)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:657)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:521)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:960)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:927)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:916)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.executeDescribeStream(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:364)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AmazonKinesisVideoClient.describeStream(AmazonKinesisVideoClient.java:336)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.StreamOps.getStreamInfo(StreamOps.java:106)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.StreamOps.createStreamIfNotExist(StreamOps.java:65)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoRendererExample.execute(KinesisVideoRendererExample.java:76)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.parser.examples.KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest.testConsumerExample(KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest.java:67)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest.testConsumerExample:67 » IllegalArgument profi...
  KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest.testDifferentResolution:52 » IllegalArgument p...
  KinesisVideoRendererExampleTest.testExample:38 » IllegalArgument profile file ...
  FragmentMetadataVisitorTest.testFragmentMetadata_NoFragementMetadata_withWebm:269 » NoSuchFile
  FrameRendererTest.frameCountTest:47 » Headless 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was se...
  FrameRendererTest.frameCountTest2:79 » Headless 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was s...
  SimpleFrameVisitorTest.testWithWebmVideo:71->getClustersByteSource:120->getInputStreamParserByteSource:124 » NoSuchFile

Tests run: 73, Failures: 7, Errors: 0, Skipped: 6

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  05:36 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-05T08:15:19Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /tmp/samcli/scratch/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
SAM Build has failed: Command did not exit successfully, exit code: 1
2 has failed: Command did not exit successfully, exit code: 1
```

Comment: In order to help us help you, it would be great if you can show exactly what errors you are getting, and please do it by pasting the error *text* into a code block - screenshots, especially from external sites that may be deleted in the future - are not a good idea: they make it harder to understand your questions, and as a result you are less likely to get an answer.

Comment: @Guss Hello, I am so sorry, I am using stackoverflow for the first time. I have edited my question, can you please check with it.